# How to fix undefined divs in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**For Example I Type**

```
var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('js-ticket-count');
```

undefined & HtmlCollection !

```
x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('js-ticket-count')[0];
```

it return as undefined ? why ?

**Html Code :**

```
<div class='js-ticket-count'>
<p id='style-1'>test<p>
<p id='style-1'>test<p>
<p id='style-1'>test<p>
<p id='style-1'>test<p>
<p id='style-1'>test<p>
<div>
**More Html Stuff Here**
 </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Are you running your JS before the actual elements have been rendered to the page? Also, all your paragraph tags aren't closed properly. They should be `</p>`. Finally, IDs **must** be unique

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection, but this collection can be empty if nothing matched. Then, getting `[0]` will indeed return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can use `DOMContentLoaded` event to make sure that document is loaded like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
    var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('js-ticket-count');
        x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('js-ticket-count')[0];
    console.log(x1)
})
```

- you can also use `load` event on window object like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('js-ticket-count');
        x1 = document.getElementsByClassName('js-ticket-count')[0];
    console.log(x1)
})
```

- also make sure that your `script` tag on before of `body` tag close  to make sure that the every element is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your JS inside an onload listener. Otherwise it's likely your JS is running before the elements have loaded into the DOM.

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert(document.getElementsByClassName('js-ticket-count')[0]);
}
```

The `HtmlCollection` you're seeing is basically an array of elements, as there may be multiple elements with a certain class name. You're returning the first element with `[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are using the external JS file then maybe add it at the end of the body element. So your JS file will load after all the HTML elements have been loaded. In this way, JS can read the HTML element. Something like this:

```
<body>
    <div class='js-ticket-count'>
    <p id='style-1'>test<p>
    <p id='style-1'>test<p>
    <p id='style-1'>test<p>
    <p id='style-1'>test<p>
    <p id='style-1'>test<p>
    <div>
    **More Html Stuff Here**
     </div></div>
     
     <script srs="externalJSlink.js"></script>
</body>
```